# Prove that $\{(x,y): W_x\text{ and }W_y\text{ are recursively separable}\}$ is $\Sigma_3$-complete

Tags: computability, recursion

> Prove that $\{(x,y): W_x\text{ and }W_y\text{ are recursively separable}\}$ is $\Sigma_3$-complete

This is a question from Soare's Recursively Enumerable Sets and Degrees. I have little idea how to construct the reduction function. I have done much simpler completeness proofs of $\Sigma_1$ level but don't really get the intuition behind completeness at higher levels of the hierarchy.

Comment: You might try using the fact that $\mathrm{Tot}=\{e:|W_{e}|=\infty\}$ is $\Pi_{2}$ complete. So any $\Sigma_{3}$ set $A$ is of the form $x \in A$ iff $\exists y \langle x, y \rangle \in \mathrm{Tot}$ or something like that.

Comment: My definition of $\mathrm{Tot}$ was off (though still $\Pi_{2}$) complete. It should be the set of indices $e$ such that $W_{e} = \omega$. The point is that $W_{x}$ and $W_{y}$ are recursively separable iff  there is $e \in \mathrm{Tot}$ such that $W_{x} \subset W_{e}$ and $W_{y} \subset \omega-W_{e}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that sounds more like a strategy to place the set in the hierarchy right? I don't have an issue with proving that the set is $\Sigma_3$. My problem is in constructing a function from the general $\Sigma_3$ set to this one.

Comment: No, my point is that the general $\Sigma_{3}$ set can be expressed as $\mathrm{Tot}'$, which is easier to work with.

Comment: I realize that my comments are muddled. Hopefully they're helpful!

Comment: To go further, what about the complexity of this set under the hypothesis of being effectively separable instead of recursively separable ?